# Share pdf-tools installation between computers?

Tags: pdf-tools

**Q:** how do I share a `pdf-tools` installation between computers?

I use [`pdf-tools`](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) on two
difference machines, and sync my `.emacs.d` between them via
Dropbox.

I have installed `pdf-tools` through
the
[package manager](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html). `pdf-info-epdfinfo-program` points to the executable `epdfinfo`,
which `pdf-tools` builds when installing.  That's apparently a problem.

Formerly, I ran one machine on MacOS and another on Linux
(Fedora), and neither one could use the other's `epdfinfo`
executable.  I now run one machine with Fedora and another with
Ubuntu, and, surprisingly, I have the same problem despite both
being Linux: the Fedora machine can't use the Ubuntu machine's
`epdfinfo` and vice-versa.  The error message suggests that it cannot one of the `poppler` libraries:

> pdf-info-check-epdfinfo: Error running ‘/home/dan/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/pdf-tools-20170417.150/epdfinfo’: /home/dan/Dropbox/.emacs.d/packages/pdf-tools-20170417.150/epdfinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What I have done in the past is:

1) install `pdf-tools` on one machine and save a copy of its
  executable (say, as `epdfinfo-alt`),

2) install `pdf-tools` on the other machine,

3) copy `epdfinfo-alt` into the `pdf-tools` directory,

4) put a conditional statement in my `init` file like:

```
;; pseudocode
(when (eq machine machine-alt)
  (setq pdf-info-epdfinfo-program
        "some-directory/epdfinfo-alt"))
```

Surely there is a better way to share a `pdf-tools` install
between machines that are not running the same operating
system or flavor of Linux.  How do I do it without going to all
this fiddly trouble?

Comment: What do you mean by 'neither one could use the other's epdfinfo'? What error did Emacs report when you tried? If you can solve the problem by saving the file in another location, it suggests there may be an issue with permissions or the executable bit - the name and location shouldn't matter on their own?

Comment: @Tyler: I've posted the error message.  It can't find one of the shared libraries with which the executable is built (it relies on poppler).

Comment: does your workaround, steps 1-4, require you compile epdfinfo on both machines, or have you been able to compile epdfinfo on one machine and use it on the other after renaming it? I suspect the libpoppler library has a different name or location on each system, a problem you shouldn't be able to fix just by renaming the executable

Comment: @Tyler: I wasn't clear enough.  I install `pdf-tools` on each machine, which, in turn, compiles a different `epdfinfo` on each machine.  However, I don't have to deal with the poppler issues once I have the two compiled executables, because I have the janky conditional statement in the init file that uses the executable made by the current machine.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. In that case, it seems clear that you can't cross-compile epdfinfo to work on both systems, at least not without some non-trivial tinkering. So the problem comes down to Dropbox syncing the executable, when you'd rather it be ignored so you can have a different file on each machine? I could offer suggestions, but they end up being similarly janky to what you're already doing.

Comment: @Tyler: thanks for the thoughts.  I think the problem is that the *package* creates a system-specific executable, rather than relying on an extra executable that's already on the system (eg, by packaging `epdfinfo` as something one installs on the system, separate from `pdf-tools`).  I've noticed a roughly analogous problem with `emms`, which is not purely elisp (it now includes a program written in C called `emms-print-metadata`, which is frustrating to deal with).

Comment: this is a long-standing feature request https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/154

Comment: @Tyler : I think that means the answer is “there isn’t a non-fiddly way to do it.”  If you post that link to the issue request and give a brief explanation for the benefit of future readers, I’ll accept it.

Comment: You should set-up the `pdf-info-epdfinfo-program` variable conditionally according to the sytem that's currently running before loading `pdf-tools`.  Then the package should pick-up that path, verify that the exe is ok or compile it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdf-tools requires a separate executable, `epdfinfo`, in order to function. This executable is distributed as source code within the pdf-tools package. As such, it gets compiled whenever you install or update the pdf-tools package.

This is convenient, as it provides one-step installation of the pdf-tools package, which includes code for installing the dependencies for `epdfinfo` automatically.

This is also a hassle, as it means `epdfinfo` gets compiled with every update of pdf-tools, whether or not it has actually changed. And, as you've discovered, it makes it non-trivial to sync your emacs config across different computers.

Syncing should work between any two computers on which the dependencies of `epdfinfo` have the same names and locations. That should mean computers with the same distro version (i.e., two machines that both run Debian Wheezy, or that both run Ubuntu 14.4), or that at least have the same file system hierarchy and library structure (i.e., Ubuntu 17 and the version of Debian that it was built from). But systems with different file system hierarchies or library packaging (Fedora vs Ubuntu) or OS (Mac vs Linux) will not produce cross-compatible binaries, so syncing won't work.

This issue has been raised with the [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/154) developer, and he's receptive to splitting `epdfinfo` into a separate installation, eventually.